# Delete some text and change html tag with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im looking a way to change the following HTML:

```
<div class="votes">Rating: <strong>+5</strong> (from 5 votes)</div>
```

and produce:

```
<div class="votes"><div class="calculated-rating">+5</div></div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.votes').each(function(){
        votes = jQuery('strong',this).html();
        jQuery(this).html('<div class="calculated-rating">'+votes+'</div>');
    });                         
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/68CjG/

Answer (score 0):

Its little short.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var tmp = jQuery(".votes strong").html();
jQuery(".votes").html('<div class="calculated-rating">'+tmp+'</div>')
});
</script>
```

Comment: this will only work if there is one instance of .votes, otherwise every .votes div will show the value of the first instance.